# coreplot several times within the same day

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I'm writing an app to track glucose level for diabetics. They will be checking their glucose level several time per day. Is it possible to format the graph so it shows the date once and then the individual times above the date on the x axis?
Sort of like this:
|8:45|12:15|5:20|
|## 11-1-17 ##  |

I can't display it here but the date should appeared centered under the three times

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can label the major tick locations with the date and minor tick locations with the time.